# Change SAMBA password in LDAP with Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap, samba, openldap

I am using Apache Directory Studio to administer a small LDAP database, and I am planning to stop using LAM for user and group management because it lacks groupOfUniqueNames support.

I have only one problem: how can I change SAMBA passwords? There is a tool that checks and generates hashes, but apparently it doesn't recognize SAMBA NTLM. Is there a script or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to keep Samba and LDAP passwords in sync is to deploy the `smbk5pwd` overlay (despite the name, it can be configured without Kerberos), which updates Samba password hashes in response to LDAP Password Modify operations, and configure Samba with `ldap password sync = only`. Note that this depends on your clients properly issuing Password Modify operations and not simply writing to the `userPassword` attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it now. Do you know if Apache Directory Studio sends this command?

Comment: I don't use Apache DS so I can't say for sure, but it looks like it does not, as the ticket is open and unresolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-648